# For 128 bit hash function, what is the best method to select?

Tags: security, hash, md5, murmurhash

For 128 bit hash method, there are several choices like, md5 and murmur3, which is the best?

Comment: Do you need collision resistance, or only (second) preimage resistance?

Comment: MD5 is broken regarding collisions, and murmur3 isn't a cryptographic hash.

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirements. Do you want to protect against an attacker, or only against accidents.

Answer (score 3):

From the security perspective they are all bad because 128 bit is nowadays much too short.

Therefore you want a cryptographically secure hash take e.g. RIPEMD-160 (which is AFAIR not as much broken as SHA-1).

If don't need real security it doesn't matter if you use md5 or murmur3 or whatever 128 bit hash.

Comment: Much too short is exaggerating the matter a bit, brute forcing a 128 bit collision is still pretty hard, and brute-forcing a 128 pre-image is practically impossible. Still I'd use a 160+ bit hashfunction if collision resistance is required.